# Coordinates of the lowest point in polygon

Tags: qgis, dem, coordinates, qgis-2, elevation

I am working in QGIS 2.6. I have a file of several polygons and I want for each one, to find the lowest point (where is it located and its elevation).

I am using `"Grid statistics for polygons"` which gives me the elevation but not the coordinates of this lowest point.

How can I find these coordinates? Is there an existing tool in QGIS to perform this?

Comment: What kind of format are your polygons? Vector or raster data? When you say "lowest", do you mean the lowest y coordinate value or an actual data value ("elevation")?

Comment: My polygons are vector data. And indeed when I say "lowest" I refer to the elevation. I use a DEM to get the lowest value when using "Grid statistics for polygons"

Answer (score 1):

I can propose a (lengthy) solution using existing tools in QGIS.

Assumption:

- The area is not large and the computer used to perform this is pretty powerful.
- The "Grid statistics for polygons" output and the "Elevation raster" files are available.

Steps:

1. Use the "Grid values to points" tool to generate a point file for the concerned area. (Select options as shown below)

[Warning: This output point file can become very large for large areas or high resolution elevation data; and will make your computer non-responsive. Please try on a smaller area / dataset first.]

[image]

2. Perform "Join attribute by location" on points layer created in step 1 (target layer) and the "Grid statistics for polygons" output (join layer).

The output from step 2 should have geometry columns (lat & long), ID and minimum elevation of the corresponding polygons. A simple attribute query or sorting based on elevation will help you select the point having minimum elevation in each polygon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this solution, but my area is too large (entire Switzerland) so my computer has difficulties to compute it.

Comment: You could try running this on each polygon basis.